# How to uniquely identify someone in oAuth

Tags: oauth

I'm currently creating a web app using Google's oAuth. I was wondering how I can uniquely identify an authenticated user so I don't accidentally add duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this would be to use OpenID with the oAuth extension (aka hybrid).

Comment: isn't it vice versa: oauth with openid extension? And isns't openid connect is not final yet and noone supports it?

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't Google give you other unique params like user name or user ID?

For example, Twitter and Facebook, give you user name and a unique url that identifies user's profile picture. If you save that params on server-side you can identify user next time that he comes on your site.

Comment: That's precisely the problem. As far as I can see they don't. All they return is the token and token_secret.

Comment: Yeah, i think you should check if you can get some user's params querying google with those tokens, and store them in your db.

Comment: Well I have, for example, been able to get their email address by parsing a Gmail feed. But: a) it's far from ideal (extra request causes latency) and b) It's not permanently unique because users can change their email address if they want [at least that's what Google says]

Answer (score 0):

I am currently using OAuth exclusively and I am requesting the https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo#email scope as described on http://sites.google.com/site/oauthgoog/Home/emaildisplayscope to get the email address of the authenticated user. I am using the email address to uniquely identify the user. This should be good enough for now.

***Edited:***

According to a recent Google developer comment (https://groups.google.com/group/oauth2-dev/browse_thread/thread/cf5c137f872f9932), they are currently working on this problem, but for anything production ready, you should use OpenID authentication.

Answer (score -1):

You should save somewhere the user_id you have for your users in your site, along with the corresponding access_token and access_token_secret.

Then you can query that table (or wherever you save that information) with the user_id and obtain the proper tokens

Regards

Comment: I'm not sure how that helps. The problem is that a different token/token_secret is provided every time a user signs in -- even if it's the same user. So if a user connects an account a second time (for whatever reason), my script would not be able to tell that it's a duplicate, and would add it. I would want a way to prevent that.

Comment: Check if the user has already a token, if so use that, if not perform the OAuth workflow.

Comment: That only helps if a user can only add one account. However, in many apps, users can authenticate multiple accounts